# Display Javascript variable with quotes in

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I have a variable that is part of a repeating list that when I use console.log can see the string with quotes in but when printed chops everything beyond that off.

```
function sendToPackList(){
          for(let i = 0; i < $('[name="tempQuant[]"]').length; i++){
              if($('[name="tempQuant[]"]')[i].value > 0){
                packItem++;
                let temprow = $('[name="tempQuant[]"]').eq(i).parent().parent().parent().parent();
                let tempDesc = temprow.find('[name="tempDesc[]"]')[0].value
                console.log(tempDesc);
                let tempWeight = temprow.find('[name="tempWeight[]"]')[0].value
                let tempQuant = temprow.find('[name="tempQuant[]"]')[0].value
                $('#packlistItems').append('<div class="row"><div class="6u"><div style="position:relative">
    <input type="text" name="goodsDesc[]" onkeyup="stockAutocomplete(this)" autocomplete="off" value="'+tempDesc+'"></div></div></div>
```

variable is named tempDesc and holds string 48" monitor, and displays as that at console.log statement. However when it gets to value="'+tempDesc'" it displays only the word 48. I have tried adding slashes before the quotes but with no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `escape()` function. your could should use it like this: `escape(tempDesc)`. It is needed here because you have to escape the quote in order to archive that its proceeded like a normal char and not as the end of the enquoted string like in:

"this String is in "quotes" but still has quotes in it".

`"this String is in \"quotes\" but still has quotes in it".`

Comment: Thats great thanks, I get the full string but with %22%20 in now. Which is progress. I think I'll be able to sort this now. Thanks again.

Comment: While this is the correct answer, it would be nice for anyone else visiting this question to know why escaping `tempDesc` is needed.

Comment: Hi. The script that sends tempDesc is in PHP. I am editing a document that an ex colleague set up so unfortunately I don't know why he has done it that way. Sorry I am relatively new to this.
For anyone else, to complete the function, i have used replace() to replace double quotes. - i.e. tempDesc.replace(/%22/g, '&quote');